# Node.js Express: sending file and array as response

Tags: node.js, express

We are using Express to create an API/gateway.
In the backround the endpoint calling some business logic and we sending a file back.
One standard application which is calling this API is a website.
For this we want to send next to the file some information to render describing the result of the business logic.

Our current solution:
Generating JSON which contains on the one hand the encoded binary file as a buffer on the other hand an array of information to render.
Sending this JSON as response.

Problem is that this is an individual solution.
We wondered if there is a standard method to resolve such a situation?

Comment: Combine them and send as an array

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What is the advantage of an array over a json -Object?

Comment: You can send array and object both as respond. Sending array is very simple `res.json(yourArray)` similar to sending object as respond `res.json(youObj)`. JSON support both object and array if you want to send collection send it as array otherwise you can sand object.